# In how many ways 10 pebbles can be arranged into five buckets so that each bucket has the same number of pebbles?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Ten pebbles are thrown into five different buckets all equidistance with an equal chance of ending up in any five buckets.

This can result in different distributions. For example, all the ten pebbles can end up in one single bucket let’s say bucket 1 then there is only one way of getting this distribution. In other words; We can say that there is only one way to arrange all ten pebbles into one single bucket (bucket-1).

But I am interested in how many unique ways that 10 pebbles can be arranged in five different buckets so that we get the same number of pebbles in each bucket i.e 2 pebbles in each bucket. In other words, in how many unique ways we can get a uniform distribution from the experiment as below?

[image]

Comment: Are the pebbles identical? Are the buckets identical etc... and what is your approach for the question?

Comment: @AnuragA I have updated the question hope it helps!! I am absolutely clueless on approaching this

Comment: Problem Statement Questions are generally frowned upon here.   What have you tried? What are your thoughts? What is the context of hte problem?

Comment: 1) If the pebbles are identical then there is only one way, 2 in each box. 2) If they are not identical, and neither are the boxes, then pick 2 for box 1, pick 2 of the remaining 8 for box 2, etc. 3) If pebbles distinct but boxes identical, then modify the answer to (2) accordingly.

Comment: Do not confuse the questions of "*how many ways...*" which is rather ambiguous and "*what is the probability that...*" You talk about "*chances*"... Are you wanting to ask the probability question instead?

Comment: @Ned, Alan, Jmoravitz ; thank you for the feedback, I have restructured and edited the question again. It seems like the wrong use of the word "identical pebbles" was one of the sources of confusion. Please let me know if confusion persists and also let me know that the question itself isn't valid

Comment: Right... so... if the pebbles were all *distinctly labeled* and one "*outcome/arrangement*" is considered different than another so long as at least one of the labeled pebbles is in a different place in the one arrangement than the other arrangement... as Ned already alluded to, you can pick which two of the pebbles go in the first box, which two of those remaining go in the second, etc... for a total of $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ which you should recognize as being the multinomial coefficient $\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}=\dfrac{10!}{(2!)^5}$

Answer (score 1):

answered by @JMoravitz above

> Right... so... if the pebbles were all distinctly labeled and one
> "outcome/arrangement" is considered different than another so long as
> at least one of the labeled pebbles is in a different place in the one
> arrangement than the other arrangement... as Ned already alluded to,
> you can pick which two of the pebbles go in the first box, which two
> of those remaining go in the second, etc... for a total of
> $\binom{10}{2} \binom{8}{2} \binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$ which you should recognize as being the
> multinomial coefficient  $\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}$ = $\frac{10!}{(2!)^{5}}$